# Is the syntax for the $.ajax() function here incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to use .ajax to read the source html of a given url (int his case www.wikipedia.org) into the body of a document. The code below is intended to do this, but it is not returning the (perhaps erroneously) expected result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'www.wikipedia.org', success: function(data) { 
            $('body').append(data); 
        } 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why it's not functioning, and perhaps how to remedy the situation so that when the page is rendered the html for the link is displayed in the document body?

Comment: `url: 'http://www.wikipedia.org'`

Comment: Then Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Curious, but why do you need ajax to do this?

Comment: Huey - what other options are there? I don't have a special attachemt to ajax, but since I would like to work from within a javascript code it seemed the most obvious solution. I would love to hear other suggestions.

Comment: Take a note http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Musa - There is a jQuery plugin that lets you make cross domain requests. Maybe he has it in his code?

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending http:// to the URL, i.e., http://www.wikipedia.org

Comment: This will get the OP past the original problem and then onto the Same Origin issue.

Comment: How to deal with the SO issue?

Comment: @JustinGreenough - This is how: https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

Answer (score 0):

As Mike said, you need to add `http://` to the start of the url.

There is also a same-origin issue. In order to request a page via AJAX and read the result, it normally has to be on the same domain as you.

The best way to solve this is to use a proxy for the request. You could either [setup your own](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) or use [an existing service](http://www.corsproxy.com/) (if you're comfortable with being dependent on it).

Comment: Yes I did of course try prepending the address above with http:// but the result is the same (I assumed, perhaps correctly, that the browser will first try an http type as does curl). How would I set up a proxy script?

Comment: @JustinGreenough you have to do it on the server. Browsers won't let you fetch content from random URLs unless the other sites explicitly allow it via HTTP headers.

Comment: @JustinGreenough Just FYI, a URL without a scheme is assumed to be a relative URL, e.g., `foo` becomes `http://www.mypage.com/foo` and `www.wikipedia.org` becomes `http://www.mypage.com/www.wikipeida.org`

Comment: So would there be a way to call cURL from the cmd (I'm using Linux here) from within the js? Would you recommend I embed some Perl script which can do this trivially?

Comment: I've added a tutorial link on creating a proxy.

Comment: I've added a link to an external service you can use.